# How to render child component in the same tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, children

This may be a misunderstanding on my side, but I have the following situation:

I have a React component called DaliBox that has some intelligence (dragging, resize, etc.) that may contain inside some HTML unknown to me and assigned to the DaliBox using __dangerouslySetInnerHTML. However, if inside that HTML there is a custom tag (`<plugin />` in this case), then I want it to host a new React component (PluginPlaceholder) that will act as a DaliBox container.

What I do is, inside of the ComponentDidMount, find the `<plugin />` tags in the DOMNNode and then use a ReactDOM.render to render the PluginPlaceholder passing in the necessary props. The problem is that, when using the React DevTools extension for Chrome I can see that this creates some kind of different "tree" that forces me to update things manually.

The question is, am I doing something wrong? Is this the only way or is it possible to create the new React tree inside the old one and let React do its magic and update automatically?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: code snippets please or it never happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid `__dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as long as it possible. For your case (if I get it right) you don't need one.

Let's consider `<DaliBox />` and markup `<div><p><PluginPlaceholder /></p></div>`. From your question I understand that you have function to parse this markup somehow. So let's consider function `parseMarkup` that returns something like

```
[
  component: 'div',
  children: [
    component: 'p',
    children: [
      component: 'PluginPlaceholder'
    ]
  ]
]
```

No you can render your tree without any kind of magic with something like:

```
renderChildren(markup) {
  let component;
  let children = [];
  // get component. PluginPlaceholder or just string like 'div' or 'p'
  switch (markup.component) {
    case 'PluginPlaceholder':
      component = PluginPlaceholder;
      break;
    default:
      component = markup.component;
  }
  // recursively render children
  if (markup.children) {
    children = this.renderChildren(markup.children);
  }
  return React.createElement(component, [], children);
}

render() {
  return (
    <DaliBox>
      {this.renderChildren(parseMarkup(this.props.markup))}
    </DaliBox>
  );
}
```

I don't test this code and it probably will not work, but I hope you get the idea and can extend it for your problem

Answer (score 0):

From your description it looks like your DOM tree has multiple owners/ editors:

- `<body>`

  - ... other HTML elements --> not managed by react
  - `<DaliBox />` --> managed by react

    - ...other HTML  --> not managed by react
    - `<div id='pluginplaceholder'>`  --> not managed by react, but to be replaced with a new (recursive) react `<DaliBox>`

      - ...etcetera

This is not ideal for react (to put it mildly). It feels like you are trying to apply react to random levels in the DOM structure.
This is something jQuery allows and facilitates, but it does not go well with react.

In order of best to worst way to apply react:

- The ideal way to apply react is to give react **a complete monopoly** of 1 part of your DOM structure, *including all descendants*. Then you have one react instance, managing a specific (if not all) of your DOM/ HTML.
- Less ideal, but still common practice: apply react to multiple unrelated parts of your DOM structure. By having multiple react instances (multiple `ReactDOM.render()`s).
- Even less ideal, but maybe acceptable if absolutely unavoidable: give react complete monopoly over 1 (or more) parts of your DOM structure, but leave out the lowest levels. By applying `_dangerouslySetInnerHTML()` to those lowest levels.
- Recipe for disaster, to be avoided at all cost: have react manage DOM level 1-4 in a tree, but not level 5 and 6, and another react instance to manage DOM level 7 and lower.

In your recursive case, I would advise to stick to the ideal situation: not use `_dangerouslySetInnerHTML()` at all.
Or rethink the specific parts of your code/ behavior/ DOM where react is applicable. (maybe you do not need react in the drag/drop part of your DOM).

The reason behind this: react relies on its own (hidden) virtual copy of the DOM *and relies on the virtual copy and the DOM to always be in sync*. If some other code starts messing with DOM-parts that react is supposed to manage, then your virtual DOM and real DOM are no longer in sync, and your react code will quickly produce unpredictable results, and become completely undebuggable.

Comment: I know what I have is not the optimal, but I wasn't able to think of something better. I work in a huge project with lots of things moving at the same time. Anyway, thanks for the comprehensive response :)